# How can I fix this error relating to DINet and Openface?

Tags: python, opencv, openfaces

So I'm trying to use DINet and OpenFace to do some AI lip syncing but I keep getting this error and don't know what to do?

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.18) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:743: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

I've tried doing a fresh reinstall of anaconda, python etc... nothing changed. Tried reinstalling windows and then trying again, nothing happened.